# Obtener url aleatoria del feeds

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

Hola resulta que tengo la duda de como obtener la **url** de cualquier entrada publicada usando el **feeds** tengo el siguiente código pero no da el resultado que necesito.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
var post = src='/feeds/posts/default?published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=labelthumbs&amp;max-results=3' 

var direcciones = new Array(
"post"
)

function enlaceAleatorio(){
aleat=Math.random()*direcciones.length;aleat=Math.floor(aleat);return direcciones[aleat]}
//]]></script>

<a href='enlaceAleatorio();'>Navegar</a>
```

Busco alguna manera de lograr que aparezca un enlace aleatorio extraído del feeds.

Sin que sea el del feeds. ejemplo: `http://miblogs.com/feeds/posts/default`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El código que estás intentando utilizar es muy viejo, y Blogger ya no soporta esa forma de obtener un JSON con el feed de tu blog.

Lo que corre ahora es la API JSON:

https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/getting_started

Esencialmente tenés que generar una API key [desde acá](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/json/using#APIKey) y luego cargar el JSON desde una URL como:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v2/blogs/TU-ID-DE-BLOG?key=TU-API-KEY
```

Luego utilizá la misma metodología del código que citaste en tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta igual no logro a ser funcionar el código . me pregunto si existe otra manera de obtener la url de las entradas del blogs sin la API solo javascript